# Требуется помощь в решении задачи

Tags: python, олимпиада

Сразу скажу: я понимаю, что тут платформа не для решения задач, но я прошу не решить её, а оптимизировать моё решение или привести своё, более логичное.

Ваня с детства мечтал создавать компьютерные игры. Когда он вырос, то смог устроиться в компанию "Игродел" на должность разработчика. Первой задачей было написание генератора уровней к игре "Линия".

Игровой уровень "Линии" предсталяет собой множество из N клеток, расположенных вдоль одной прямой и пронумерованных от 0 до N - 1. Каждая клетка может быть в одном из состояний:

- в клетке стоит персонаж
- в клетке находится препятствие: змеи, шипы или лава
- клетка свободна

Цель главного героя - добраться до клетки с номером N - 1. Единственное, что он может делать - перепрыгивать через непустое множество препятствий (клетка, в которую прыгает персонаж, должна быть свободна). Каждый раз, когда персонаж совершает прыжок, в точке, откуда он прыгнул, равновероятно возникает одно из препятствий.

Сегодня Ваня доделал генератор уровней. И всё было бы хорошо, если не одно "но": Ваня не знает, возможно ли пройти уровень, который получится на выходе генератора. Справиться с этой задачей он не смог. Поэтому Ваня обратился к вам за помощью.

Формат ввода:
В первой строке входных данных задано одно целое число: 2 ≤ N ≤ 100000. Во второй строке входных данных задана строка S, состоящая из N символов. Строка S описывает игровое поле и состоит из символов:

- 'X' - клетка, в которой находится главный герой;
- '?' - клетка, в которой находятся змеи;
- '#' - клетка, в которой находится шипы;
- '*' - клетка, в которой находится лава;
- '.' - свободная клетка

Гарантируется, что X всегда есть.

Формат вывода:
На первой и единственной строке выведите одно слово:

- YES, если существует последовательность прыжков после которой персонаж окажется в клетке с номером N - 1;
- NO, иначе.

```
n = int(input())
s = input()
flag = True
if s[-1] == 'X':
    flag = True
elif s[-1] != '.':
    flag = False
else:
    person = s.find('X')
    pos = 0
    flag = True
    for x in range(person+1,len(s)):
        if s[x] == '.':
            if pos == 0:
                flag = False
                break
            pos = 0
        else:
            pos = 1
if flag:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

На сайте, на котором я решаю приведено только три примера  примера ввода и вывода,на 19 тесте программа выдаёт неверный ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я пробовал много разных вариантов "Линии", но все работает верно, но на 19 неверный ответ.
Вот первые три теста:

1. 3; X..  ->  NO
2. 4; X#?.  ->  YES
3. 5; X?.?.  ->  YES

Comment: Для `4`, `.*X.` вы вернёте `NO`.  Правильный ответ `YES`.

Comment: Единственное, что он может делать - перепрыгивать через непустое множество препятствий. Поэтому, по идее, все правильно выводит

Comment: Он может прыгнуть налево, затем направо и выиграть. Я где-то ошибся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выиграть необходимо чтобы последняя клетка была или пуста или уже занята *X*. Необходимо но не достаточно.

Второе необходимое условие: рядом с *X* должно быть препятствие. Иначе невозможно сделать первый ход.

Если оба условия выполнены, продолжаем.

Клетку назовём *болотом* если она...

1. ... рядом с *X* справа от него;
2. ... справа от *X* и перед ней пустая клетка.

Пример:

> ```
> ..*X..*...
>     --  --
>     болотные клетки подчёркнуты
> ```

Если болот нет, *X* выиграл. Иначе из всех болот выберем самое левое. *X* или уже стоит рядом с болотом (случай 1) или может до него доскакать (потому что оно самое левое). Когда *X* оказался рядом с болотом, единственный ход - прыжок налево. Он возможен если слева от *X* где-то есть пустое место. После прыжка болот становится на одно меньше.

Пусть *S* - число болот, *V* - число пустых клеток слева от *X*.

Утверждение: если *S ≤ V*, то *X* выигрывает прыгая направо когда возможно и налево в противном случае (упёрся в болото).

Доказывается по индукции по *S*: оба числа *S* и *V* убывают на единицу одновременно. Когда *S* обнулилось, выигрыш обеспечен.

Утверждение: если *S > V*, то *X* проиграл.

Чтобы убрать одно болото (уменьшить *S* на единицу) нужно уменьшить *V* на единицу. Когда *V* обнулится, останется непреодолимое болото.

```py
def win(s):
    if s[-1] == 'X':
        return True
    if s[-1] != '.':
        return False

    i = s.index('X')
    if (i == 0 or s[i - 1] == '.') and s[i + 1] == '.':
        return False

    b = 1 if s[i + 1] == '.' else 0
    for j in range(i + 2, len(s)):
        if s[j - 1] == '.' and s[j] == '.':
            b += 1

    v = s[:i].count('.')

    return b <= v


input()
print('YES' if win(input()) else 'NO')
```